# Redux-Toolkit createAsyncThunk Dispatch is showing as undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

Using Redux-Toolkit, I am trying to use ThunkAPI & dispatch inside an `createAsyncThunk` but I am getting rejected because of type error. Not sure how to resolve this.

my store:

```
export const store = configureStore({ 
    reducer: rootReducer, 
    middleware: [...getDefaultMiddleware()],
});
```

my Action:

```
export const tester = createAsyncThunk(
    'tester',
    async (testData, {dispatch}) => { 
        await dispatch(load(true));
        const final = await someExternalFunc(testData)
        return final;
    }
);
```

but, I am getting output as
[image]

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Please make a **reproducible** example: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), there is no indication that it is the source of the error, better make a sandbox [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla-react-template-irhcq), and please add actual code instead of images.

Comment: Instead of destructuring the thunkAPI object could you pass the full object in and see if the dispatch method is defined there ?

Comment: @OmarNasr, even If I have ```thunkAPI``` instead of ```{dispatch}``` I am getting thunkAPI as undefined when I do a console.log.

Comment: Where and how are you dispatching this thunk?  (Also, you shouldn't need to call `getDefaultMiddleware()` yourself in that store setup snippet if you're not customizing anything - you can leave it out entirely.)

Comment: So you don't calling `tester` right, show the whole code.

Comment: @markerikson I am dispatching thunk from another function 
```
export function testCalling() {
    return async (dispatch, getState) => {
        dispatch(loading(true));
        const state = getState().uiState;
        await dispatch(tester(value).then(details => {
           dispatch(value(true)
            });
        dispatch(loading(false));
    };
}
```
My use-case is to wait until promise is resolved to set my react state to trigger another event. please suggest if this can be done even without createAsyncThunk

Comment: @markerikson This is the codesandbox link codesandbox.io/s/redux-toolkit-pdpsk?file=/src/features/todo/… when we click fetchTodo, we can see undefined in console, Is there a way we can access getState & dispatch from the place where it shows undefined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your comment, you are not calling the thunk right.

Calling `test()` returns an action, then you should dispatch the action:

```
const fetchTodo = createAsyncThunk("todo/fetchTodo", async (args, thunkAPI) => {
  console.log(thunkAPI, "thunkAPI");
  const response = await todoAPI();
  return JSON.stringify(response);
});

dispatch(test(testData));
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I have tried this, but My use-case is to wait until promise is resolved to set my react state to trigger another event. please suggest if this can be done even without createAsyncThunk

Comment: Cant help you without a reproducible example like I mentioned before.

Comment: This is the codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-toolkit-pdpsk?file=/src/features/todo/todoSlice.js
when we click fetchTodo, we can see undefined in console

Comment: @sai https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-toolkit-bwbzd?file=/src/features/todo/todoSlice.js, you log the args and not the `thunkAPI`

Comment: Pleas help me How to access getState and Dispatch from here if I am doing this wrong?

Comment: I just showed you how to access thunk API, just use thunkAPI.getState(), thunkAPI.dispatch(), what is the problem? Please actually visit the link I shared

Comment: Thanks @Dennis, This is helpful, I wasn't aware of args, Now It makes sense. Sorry for being stupid :)

Comment: Hi Dennis, I am facing the same problem but I am not sure I understood your solution. But Here I modified your sandbox with my issue https://codesandbox.io/s/rtk-stackoverflow-mfb2v?file=/src/features/todo/todoSlice.js , Here what I am trying to do is during the fetching todo's, I also want to increment number which is different action in the reducer. So I am dispatching the action from `fetchTodo` to change the value of increment. But it is not changing increment value. I am not sure, Is it possible or not.